# Duplicate posts from smartphones

Tags: php, mobile

I have made a simple PHP+MySQL blog-like website. Sometimes (rarely), when users post a post from a smartphone, this post got duplicated after a couple of days. Sometimes more then once. And the duplicates are in wrong character encoding.

Is it a known issue? Is there something to do with it?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it could be related to the cache?

Comment: Could you please explain it more detailed? Is it a browser cache? Does the cache resend post data?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it is happening. I cleared out that the wrong encoding is a quite rare case. But overall about 2% of all posts on my site was duplicated. I solved this with the following technique. I add a unique "form identifier" (a timestamp) as a hidden field to my post HTML form. Than, when the form is posted, in the php script I check, did the arrived form ID already saved for the current user, and if so, I just ignore this post.